# What painting equipment is needed to restore a derelict wooden house?

Tags: painting, tools, sanding, sander

The exterior walls are in a very bad shape, and the whole house needs to be painted.

It looks like this:

[image: queenslander]

What equipment should I get to prepare the walls and paint them?

Comment: That's gotta be lead paint. I'd clean up the ground around the house, then put insulation and siding over the old clapboard.

Comment: This Old House had a segment on this. They had a surfacer that would take a layer off to remove the paint and expose the wood. If one is rentable, it would be the way to go. If the paint has lead content, a bunny suit with air supply is applicable and depending on the municipality, quite freaky-deaky with the permitting.

Comment: To properly repaint that house would be an advanced project.  The numerous cracks visible in the clapboards have probably leaked in rain water, causing mold and rot.  Even if not, the project calls for a mind numbing amount of attention to detail, understanding flashing and caulking, as well as lots and lots of prep.  And more prep.  In a bunny suit.  Given the loving/disrepecting words 'restore' and 'derelict' I gotta ask, are you aiming to restore it and live there or just flip it to make some money?

Comment: Thanks mike, I'm planning on restoring it, and living there - so am aiming to do a painstakingly proper job.

Comment: With some patience it is doable. Some things can be done ok when you are sick and tired of the project.  Others can't. Figure out which steps are most critical, then pace yourself to have energy and spirit to do a good job on them.  All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need:

- Carbide scrapers of different sizes
- Paint spray gun (will save you TONS of time)
- Several good quality brushes -- edging and flat shapes
- Wood hardener for any isolated rotted spots of wood
- Wood filler or bondo to spot-patch rotted areas
- Extra replacement siding
- Saw(s) -- circular, oscillating multitool, etc
- Hammer, nails (galvanized)
- Aluminum flashing if needed
- GOOD quality caulk (I like to use Quad, sold at Lowe's)
- Primer (Zinnser or BIN)
- Paint

TBH, I've seen siding in much worse shape.  DO be concerned about lead exposure if that is lead paint.  Some clearer pictures of the worst problem-spots would allow us to give you an idea of other special considerations to take.